# How to authenticate a WordPress plugin by domain name?

Tags: php, curl, wordpress

I have a hybrid WordPress plugin that fetches all data using curl from the main server. Let's call it A.

B is the client that requests for data and also can send data to A.

Now every request is encrypted and authenticated using a API access keys.

But the problem here is if I copy the plugin from B to a new client site C, the moment I use the same access keys etc. the plugin starts working.

I want to be able to restrict the access of one API access key to one domain name. How can I attain that?

Comment: Suggestion: Make it part of the license you give your customers. The honest ones will follow it, the dishonest ones will find a way to break your DRM. This is a problem technology can't really solve confidently, especially when with things like wordpress people can just see your code.

Comment: Can you show the code that does the authentication? Does it use OpenSSL or Mcrypt or something else for encryption?

Comment: Hi Halfer, I use HMAC to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A suggestion by TJHX

Make it part of the license you give your customers. The honest ones will follow it, the dishonest ones will find a way to break your DRM. This is a problem technology can't really solve confidently, especially when with things like wordpress people can just see your code - By [TJHX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519348/tzhx)

I have also looked into a lot of options but the mere fact is that the user always has access to the code in the wordpress plugin and can easily make amendments to the CURL request Headers even if you encrypt it. 
All we can do it add it in our Licenses.

In my plugin, there are iframes that will be loading the data on the frontend so I am going to accept the domain name when the user buys the plugin and will check the referrers to my iframe to sort this issue out.

Thanks a lot guys for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say to include the allowed host's IP address (B) in your access key administration.

So: when B does a call, you can validate the key and the IP it's calling from.

On A, you can use something like `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to test the IP calling the script.

Two downsides: when sites move servers, the plugin will stop working. And of course, people can still spoof their IP, so there is a way to get around this, but at least you make it a lot more complicated and probably not worth the hassle for most cases.

Comment: Hi Eric, what you have shared is true. but i can't afford to stop the plugin when the site moves. It would call for unnecessary mails for clients etc